# Sitecore Content Serialization to include parent item as create only

Tags: serialization, scs, json

I am looking to serialize items in a way that configuration should CreateOnly for root item and than all the descendants should be deleted/updated & created as per normal. So far I have the following Json but it seems to be deleted all the items under settings

```
{
"name": "SiteContent",
"path": "/sitecore/content/ABCGroup/ABC",
"rules": [{
   "path": "/Settings",
   "scope": "SingleItem",
   "allowedPushOperations": "CreateOnly"
   },
],
{
   "name": "SiteSettings",
   "path": "/sitecore/content/ABCGroup/ABC/Settings",
   "scope": "DescendantsOnly",
   "rules": [
      {
        "path": "/Item Queries/*",
        "scope": "ignored"
      },
      {
      "path": "/Redirects/*",
      "scope": "ignored"
      },
      {
        "path": "/Scopes/*",
        "scope": "ignored"
      }
     ]
    
    }
```

I am trying to have /Settings Create only and the descendants should be create/update/delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding in an answer as I can't add json properly in the comments, can you try with the following?

```
{
   "name": "SiteContent",
   "path": "/sitecore/content/ABCGroup/ABC",
   "rules": [{
      "path": "/Settings",
      "scope": "SingleItem",
      "allowedPushOperations": "CreateOnly"
    }]
},
{
   "name": "SiteSettings",
   "path": "/sitecore/content/ABCGroup/ABC/Settings",
   "scope": "DescendantsOnly",
   "allowedPushOperations": "createUpdateAndDelete",
   "rules": [
      {
        "path": "/Item Queries/*",
        "scope": "ignored"
      },
      {
         "path": "/Redirects/*",
         "scope": "ignored"
      },
      {
        "path": "/Scopes/*",
        "scope": "ignored"
      }
    ]    
}
```