# Serialize parent as CreateAndUpdate but descendants as CreateOnly

Tags: serialization, scs

I'm trying to serialize a parent folder as CreateAndUpdate but the descendants as CreateOnly.

I found a similar question ([Sitecore Content Serialization to include parent item as create only](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28912/sitecore-content-serialization-to-include-parent-item-as-create-only)) but the question and answer both split the includes into separate objects in the JSON file... I'd like to avoid this if possible as I don't want to screw up the existing file structure...

I've set my include/rules as follows:

```
    {
      "name": "dictonary",
      "path": "/sitecore/content/Dictionary",
      "scope": "ItemAndDescendants",
      "allowedPushOperations": "CreateAndUpdate",
      "rules": [
        {
          "path": "*",
          "scope": "DescendantsOnly",
          "allowedPushOperations": "CreateOnly"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Will the DescendantsOnly rule override the CreateAndUpdate allowedPushOperation from it's parent?

If not, is there a way to achieve this without splitting the include up in to separate items?

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `DescendantsOnly` with `ItemAndDescendants` inside `rules` like that:

```
  {
  "name": "dictonary",
  "path": "/sitecore/content/Dictionary",
  "scope": "ItemAndDescendants",
  "allowedPushOperations": "CreateAndUpdate",
  "rules": [
    {
      "path": "*",
      "scope": "ItemAndDescendants",
      "allowedPushOperations": "CreateOnly"
    }
  ]
}
```

With this config, `Dictionary` item will be always updated and all descendants of `Dictionary` will be only created and never updated

Comment: Thanks for your help Marek!